# C# Delete line i text file if it is different than specific term

Tags: c#, text-files

I am editing a textfile and changing content from one value to another.
Everything works fine so far but I have reached a dead end when it comes to deleting a line i that file.
I want a function that reads a file with similar content as below...

> Name Peter
>
> Length 185
>
> Name Susan
>
> Length
>
> Name Harry
>
> Length 177

and removes all lines with the word Length NOT followed by anything and gives the result

> Name Peter
>
> Length 185
>
> Name Susan
>
> Name Harry
>
> Length 177

I have used the code

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(
   strLabelExportTotal,
   File.ReadAllLines(strLabelExportPreLenAdjust)
      .Select(1 => 1 == "LENGTH " ? "LENGTH 0" : 1));
```

to set that if a value after the word Length is missing  it should ad the value 0. But now I want the line to disappear...

Comment: have you tried .Select(1 => 1 == "LENGTH " ? "" : 1)); ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use below steps:

1. Read all text as string
2. Split lines into strings: `\n` as splitter
3. Remove unwanted string/line `LENGTH`
4. Combine the remaining list and write the file

Code:

```
string fileText = File.ReadAllText(path);            
var list = fileText.Split('\n').ToList();
list.Remove("LENGTH");
File.WriteAllLines(path, list);
```

OR

```
var list = File.ReadAllLines(path).ToList();
list.Remove("LENGTH");
File.WriteAllLines(path, list);
```

Comment: Why not just do `ReadAllLines()` instead of `ReadAllText()` and `Split()`?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting all the lines as an enumerable of lines, and currently you are outputting exactly the same number of lines to the output.  The `.Select()` method won't change the number of items being processed.

You probably want to change the `.Select()` method to a `.Where()` method which will only output lines that match a certain predicate.

Something such as:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(
   strLabelExportTotal,
   File.ReadAllLines(strLabelExportPreLenAdjust)
      .Where(x => x != "LENGTH "));
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] arr = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\file.txt");
string[] arr2 = arr.Cast<string>().Where(line => (line.Trim().ToLower() != "length")).ToArray();
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\file.txt", String.Join(Environment.NewLine, arr2);
```

The first line in code reads the file from path C:\file.txt and have it as an array of string ( each line is an element in this array )

The second line in code process that array and it filters and produce a new array named arr2 where the new array doesn't have any line equals to length.

The third line in code write the new array into the file C:\file.txt

Comment: FYI, you don't need the `.Cast<string>()` part - you can call `Where` on an array. You also don't need to call `.ToArray()` on the result, either, because `String.Join` works with an `IEnumerable`. And you can also use `File.WriteAllLines` instead of `File.WriteAllText`, and then you don't have call `String.Join` at all.