# Shift text file rows by one deleting the first line

Tags: c#, .net, logic

how to Shift text file rows by one after deleting a particular line based on condition xyz=true for that particular line. I want to use C#.

```
 using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(file))
        {

            while ((line = rows[rowIndex++]) != null)
            {
            if( line contains xyz )// i know the logic to find this;
               {
                  delete this line and shift all below lines one up;
                 }
                 }
           }
```

Comment: The safe way of doing this is writing undeleted lines to a temporary file and, if everything worked, swap the temporary file with the original then delete the old file. [Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324670/). Not doing this can corrupt your file if you get an IO error partway through the change.

Comment: `File.WriteAllLines(filePath, File.ReadAllLines(filePath).Where(line => !line.Contains("xyz")));` (this should work, but consider @DourHighArch comment about safely dealing with I/O errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to do this for small files (files which can be completely loaded into memory) is to use `File.ReadAllLines()` to get a `string[]` of the lines.  With this, you can loop through the array of `string`s and test each one to determine if it should be written to the new file or not.

A similar question came up recently here [C# Delete line i text file if it is different than specific term](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48518737/8915494)

If you're writing the output to a new file, you don't need to worry about moving all the later lines up, removing the entire line will also remove the line ending characters.

Hope this helps